# Python: Dictionary entries dissapear inside class

Tags: python

I'm running into a challenge regarding dictionaries in classes. I'm sure that I am overseeing something, but I am not sure what exactly. The situation is as follows:

I have a class called `NetMessageHandler`, it has the functions `onmessage()` and `rcvtcpmsg()`.
The function `onmessage()` allows other classes to hook into specific network messages that are received using callbacks, `rcvtcpmsg()` is called by the TCP client to process the raw message that was received into JSON and pass it on through the system. And finally, `_run_callbacks()` is called when a message is received.

When I call `onmessage()`, the callback is stored in a dictionary within the class. When I print() the dictionary after adding something, the result is as expected, e.g.:

```
{'systemdescription': [<function system_description_handler at 0x7f70a57ee0>]}
Length: 1
```

However, when I actually want to make a callback using the stored callbacks, The dictionary is empty all of the sudden, and the function fails. I have no idea how this happens, as I am not clearing/setting the dictionary to a new value. It appears that after the onmessage() function completes, the dictionary is emptied.

```
{}
Length: 0
```

My code so far for the class is as follows (only the relevant parts):

```py
class NetMessageHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        # Create an empty dictionary to store 
        self._callbacks = {}

    def _run_callbacks(self, type: str, data: dict[str, Any], origin: NetMessageOrigin):
        '''Runs when a message is received'''
        print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}: Running callbacks for {type}')
        print(self._callbacks)  # Added as a test, it returns an empty dictionary: '{}'
        
        # This part never runs as the dictionary is empty
        if type in self._callbacks:
            for c in self._callbacks[type]:
                c(type, data, origin)
   
    def rcvtcpmsg(self, msg: str, origin: 'TCPClient') -> None:
        '''Receive a TCP message and parse it to valid JSON, then run callbacks.'''
        data = self._parseMessage(msg)

        # Create an origin that represents the message sender
        origin = NetMessageOrigin(NetMessageOriginType.TCP, origin)

        # Run callbacks for the specific message type
        if "t" in data:
            self._run_callbacks(data["t"], data, origin)

    def onmessage(self, type:str, callback:Callable[[str, dict[str, Any], NetMessageOrigin], Any]):
        '''Adds a new callback for a specific message type.'''
        # Check if a callback for this message already exists
        if type not in self._callbacks:
            print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}: New callback array created for "{type}"')
            self._callbacks[type] = []

        if callback not in self._callbacks[type]:
            self._callbacks[type].append(callback)
            print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}: Callback added for message type "{type}"')
        else:
            print(f'{self.__class__.__name__}: Callback already existed for message type "{type}"')
        
        # The prints below output the expected value: {'systemdescription': [<function system_description_handler at 0x7f70a57ee0>]}
        print(self._callbacks)
        print("Length:", len(self._callbacks))
```

I checked the order of everything, and the callbacks are created before the first messages arrive, what could be going on here?

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious. You should check if anywhere outside of the shown code "_callbacks" is touched.

Comment: I made a really simple mistake, there were two separate instances of NetMessageHandler in use, being circulated around the rest of the code. Callbacks were set in one instance, rcvtcpmsg() was being called on the other instance. This issue can be considered solved, thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Stathis91 I suspected this might be the case, and already started writing an answer on how to verify it and avoid such scenarios. The verification part seems no longer relevant, but let me know if it's worthwhile to finalize and post.

Comment: It would definitely be useful to know how to avoid such scenarios in the future, so if you were already preparing something, I definitely think it will be useful to share, thanks!

Comment: You could add `id(self)` to your debug messages to see if they are the same.

Comment: The code that allowed 2 instances is the real bug. That code would benefit from unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no obvious reason for this arising from the provided code, it is likely to be an issue with the code calling/using this class. The most probable cause is that the calling code instantiates multiple instances of this class, each having its own `self._callbacks` dictionary, so adding to one instance would not affect the other. Considering how the class is written, the simplest way to avoid this (although I would not recommended except for debugging purposes) is to simply drop `def __init__`. By having `_callbacks` a class attribute (instead of an instance attribute), all instancemethods will simply update that one dictionary (the class's), rather than their own:

```
class NetMessageHandler():
    _callbacks = {}

    def _run_callbacks(..
        ...
```

As it seems there is no real reason for this class to have multiple instances, a better approach is to change its methods to class methods. Not only that when methods print they refer to the class - `self.__class__.__name__`, but also by making the methods bound to the class it won't matter if a callback is registered with `NetMessageHandler().onmessage()` or `NetMessageHandler.onmessage()`. The changes are as follows:

```
class NetMessageHandler():
    _callbacks = {}

    @classmethod
    def _run_callbacks(cls, type: str, data: dict[str, Any], origin: NetMessageOrigin):
        '''Runs when a message is received'''
        print(f'{cls.__name__}: Running callbacks for {type}')
        print(cls._callbacks)  # Added as a test, it returns an empty dictionary: '{}'

        # This part never runs as the dictionary is empty
        if type in cls._callbacks:
            for c in cls._callbacks[type]:
                c(type, data, origin)

    @classmethod
    def rcvtcpmsg(cls, msg: str, origin: 'TCPClient') -> None:
        '''Receive a TCP message and parse it to valid JSON, then run callbacks.'''
        data = cls._parseMessage(msg)

        # Create an origin that represents the message sender
        origin = NetMessageOrigin(NetMessageOriginType.TCP, origin)

        # Run callbacks for the specific message type
        if "t" in data:
            cls._run_callbacks(data["t"], data, origin)

    @classmethod
    def onmessage(cls, type:str, callback:Callable[[str, dict[str, Any], NetMessageOrigin], Any]):
        '''Adds a new callback for a specific message type.'''
        # Check if a callback for this message already exists
        if type not in cls._callbacks:
            print(f'{cls.__name__}: New callback array created for "{type}"')
            cls._callbacks[type] = []

        if callback not in cls._callbacks[type]:
            cls._callbacks[type].append(callback)
            print(f'{cls.__name__}: Callback added for message type "{type}"')
        else:
            print(f'{cls.__name__}: Callback already existed for message type "{type}"')

        # The prints below output the expected value: {'systemdescription': [<function system_description_handler at 0x7f70a57ee0>]}
        print(cls._callbacks)
        print("Length:", len(cls._callbacks))
```

This is not a *real* [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but it might be as close as python can get to, before going into the less common `__new__` method, or even metaclasses.